# Idiomatic Elixir to filter a list of maps by specific not null key values?

Tags: elixir

I'm brand new to elixir, and am trying to figure out the correct way to rewrite this ruby method:

```
def filter_events(events)
  events.select { |event| event[:id].present? && event[:vhost].present? }
end
```

in elixir. This is what I have so far:

```
def filter_events(events) do
  Enum.filter(events, &(Map.has_key?(&1, :id) && Map.has_key?(&1, :vhost)))
end
```

Is there a better / more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: It would be good if you included what the ruby method actually does. Also, could you explain why you don't think this is idiomatic?

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for clarification on whether this is idiomatic or not, or if there is a cleaner way to do it. I was initially thinking of using pattern matching, but I couldn't find a way to match a map's value being 'not null'. The ruby method takes an array of hashes, then returns an array containing only those hashes that have values for the two keys `id` and `vhost`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is so short, it doesn't really matter; It's readable. However, most examples, including [the ones in the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2), use an inline/anonymous function:

```
Enum.filter(events, fn(event) ->
  Map.has_key?(event, :vhost) and Map.has_key?(event, :id)
end)
```

If you're looking for something more clever, you can use pattern matching with [`Kernel.match?()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2).

```
Enum.filter(events, &match?(%{id: _, vhost: _}, &1))
```

or with an inline function:

```
Enum.filter(events, fn(event) -> match?(%{id: _, vhost: _}, event) end)
```

Since you're trying to check if the keys exist and their values aren't null, the following should work:

```
Enum.filter(events, fn(event) ->
  !is_nil(event[:vhost]) and !is_nil(event[:id])
end)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the fast and detailed response. Is there a way to match based on the value of the key itself, to check if it's there _and_ not nil? Or would I just do something like:

    `Enum.filter(events, fn(event) -> 
      event[:vhost] and event[:id]
    end)`

Comment: Yeah, something like that would by reasonable and it reads well.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help! As a side note as it's not letting me edit my above comment, the correct code would actually be:
`Enum.filter(events, fn(event) -> !is_nil(event[:vhost]) and !is_nil(event[:id]) end)`

Comment: On my Elixir 1.6.0 dev `Enum.filter(events, &match?({:id, :vhost, _}, &1))` returns an empty array for `[%{id: 42, vhost: 42}]`. It should be written as: `Enum.filter(events, &match?(%{id: _, vhost: _}, &1))` to work (and it will match `%{id: nil, vhost: nil}` which is not the same as your last example. And the last example, the only one which performs what was asked, is IMHO far from being idiomatic Elixir.

Comment: I'll update my answer. I was providing options since the question was somewhat vague.

Comment: @Soviut in the second variant: erroneous trailing `, _`, erroneous percent sign in front of `vhost`. In the third answer: missing percent sign before map definition inside `match?`, erroneous trailing `, _`. Please provide the careful answers for future readers despite that it was already accepted.

Comment: @mudasobwa You're right, it's late. I'll update again.

Answer (score 1):

I will put this answer here for the sake of diversity. In my understanding, most idiomatic way would be to pattern match inside filtering function. It might be looking longer, but it is more flexible. And it allows better handling in the case when your map might contain legit `nil` values for the desired keys (not your case, probably, but still).

```
def filter_events(events) do
  Enum.filter(events, fn
    %{id: nil} -> false        # or true if it might be nil
    %{vhost: nil} -> false     # or true if it might be nil
    %{id: _, vhost: _} -> true
    _ -> false
  end)  
end
```

When, like in your case, `nil` values are not valid and should be treated as an absence of value, it might be simplified to:

```
def filter_events(events) do
  Enum.filter(events, fn
    %{id: id, vhost: vhost} when not is_nil(id)
                             and not is_nil(vhost) -> true
    _ -> false
  end)  
end
```

---

Another approach would be to use [`Kernel.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension for that:

```
def filter_events(events) do
  for %{id: id, vhost: vhost} = e when
        not is_nil(id) and
        not is_nil(vhost) <- events, do: e
end
```

or, without pattern matching (less idiomatic):

```
def filter_events(events) do
  for e <- events, !is_nil(e[:id]), !is_nil(e[:vhost]), do: e
end
```

or, if you do not expect `nil` values, simply:

```
def filter_events(events) do
  for %{id: _, vhost: _} = e <- events, do: e
end
```